# "multiple object sets per type are not supported. the object sets 'applicationusers' and 'users' can both contain instances of type":

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<CardModel> Cards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Banners> Banner { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DbConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
     
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<E_Commerce.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this occurs after i tried to create a api controller after scaffolding this error occurs tried many solution on the internet but not resolved

Comment: `DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers` is redundant as `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` already defines this `DbSet`.